# NuxtJs Cannot read property '_normalized' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

this error show when I try to fetch some data in nuxtjs

```
Cannot read property '_normalized' of undefined
```

This is my axios request in nuxtjs :

```
 async asyncData({app}){
        var response = await app.$axios.get('/store/get-services',{params:{id:app.$auth.user.store.id}});
        return {services:response.data.services};
    }
```

this is a backend controller laravel:

```
public function store_ads(Request $req){
    if($req->user()->store->id != $req->id){
        abort(403);
    }
    $services = Store::select('id')->with('ads:id,store_id,price,title')->where('id',$req->id)->first();
    return response()->json(['services'=>$services],200);
}
```

and here is how i fetch them in my template:

```
<div class="services-list">
                        <h4 class="is-vcentered title has-text-centered has-text-grey-light" v-if="services.ads.length==0">No Services</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li v-for="service in services.ads" :key="service.id"><nuxt-link>{{service.title}}</nuxt-link></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

What is the reason?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The error was I don't pass `to` property for `<nuxt-link></nuxt-link>` and this is what causes this error

Comment: Exactly. Nuxt.js could provide a better error message than this one.

Comment: Yeah, cryptic error, how could anyone understand it without googling.

Comment: In my case was problem with undefined url for `this.$router.push(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error message. Changing the order in the `v-for`-loops solved the problem for me.

Before my `v-for` looked like this:

```
<NuxtLink v-for="(key, highlight) in highlights" :key="key" :to="highlight.url">
{{ highlight.title }}
</NuxtLink>
```

I changed the order of the attributes to:

```
<NuxtLink v-for="(highlight, key) in highlights" :key="key" :to="highlight.url">
{{ highlight.title }}
</NuxtLink>
```

Note: I used Vue.js with Nuxt.js